# Should ESP (EFI) partition be primary or logical?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader, efi

I want to create an ESP partition for my EFI on a new disk.

Should I check "Create as Primary Partition"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out: yes, I should. Otherwise the partition may risk not being seen at startup.

Comment: If you get asked this question _at all_, this indicates you're using a MBR/DOS partition table – which is permitted for UEFI, but not ideal. (For example, Windows won't like it.) You should convert the disk to GPT partitioning. (In GPT, there is no such thing as 'logical' partition, all of them are 'primary'.)